# How to include mruby after installing with rbenv/ruby-build?

Tags: rbenv, mruby

I'm trying to compile the "Source Code (.c)" example from [this tutorial](http://mruby.org/docs/articles/executing-ruby-code-with-mruby.html).

I have installed mruby using rbenv: `rbenv install mruby-1.2.0`

I get an error when trying to compile the program:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Imruby/include test_program.c -o test_program

test_program.c:1:10: fatal error: 'mruby.h' file not found
#include "mruby.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How am I supposed to reference the mruby library when installing via rbenv/ruby-build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `rbenv install mruby-1.2.0` doesn't install header files of mruby(it's only a dump of `build/host` directory after mruby is built):

```
% ls $(rbenv prefix mruby-1.2.0)
LEGAL   bin     lib     mrbgems mrblib  src
```

You need

```
# get mruby's code
git clone https://github.com/mruby/mruby.git mruby
# build mruby
cd mruby && rake
# go back to directory of `test_program.c`
cd ..
```

before `test_program.c`'s compilation instead.
And you need `mruby/build/host/lib/libmruby.a -lm` compile options too.

Answer (score 0):

add -lm

in mruby is /include directory in my source is possible -I mruby_directory/include

next add ~/mruby/build/host/lib/libmruby.a